# Getting the current page's window with the low level api of the Firefox SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

I'm creating a Firefox extension for adding some functionality to certain Web pages. I need to check that some elements do exist and highlight them, so I'm using xpath to check and locate them. I know about manipulating tabs and the content through tabs and ports, but I really need to use the low level API and do it without ports. The thing is, I don't know how to get the current opened tab window (I can also open the tab, but I'm not getting the window). I already tryed to open a tab and :

```
tabs.open({
            url: url,
            onOpen: function onOpen(tab) {

                // get the XUL tab that corresponds to this high-level tab
                var lowLevelTab = viewFor(tab);
                var browser = tab_utils.getBrowserForTab(lowLevelTab);
                var doc = browser.contentDocument;
                console.log(doc); //THIS IS AN EMPTY DOC

                // get the most recent window. This give me a XUL window, and I can't sucessfully execute eval on that...
                var win = utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
}})
```

I sawa lot of methods for retrieving different kinds of windows, but I'm not finding the explanation about the differences. E.g. Chroe window, XUL window, NSI window, base window...I just need the current Web page's document window.

Any clarification is welcome. 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to listen for another tab event:

```
onReady: function onOpen(tab) {

                var content = utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().content;
                var domInstances = content.document.evaluate(me.getTemplateXpath(), content.document, null, 4, null);
                var res = domInstances.iterateNext();                   
                while (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    res.style["background-color"] = "orange";
                    res = domInstances.iterateNext();
                }
                callback();
}
```